# Quadratic Program Reformulation

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have the quadratic program
$$\max\quad  \mu^Tx+r_fx_0-\gamma \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|-\frac{\lambda}{2}x^TVx$$
$$\text{s.t. }\quad \mathbb{1}^Tx+x_0=1$$
where $\mu$, $r_f$, $\gamma$, $\lambda$, and all $y_i$ are known constants and $V$ is positive definite symmetric. I need to reformulate the problem into the standard form
$$\min \quad f^Tx+\frac{1}{2}x^THx$$
$$\text{s.t.} \quad Ax \leq b, \;\;A_{eq}x=b_{eq}, \;\;l\leq x \leq u$$
I've tried to negate the objective function and make a few substitutions but I can't seem to identify $H$, $f$, $A_{eq}$, $b_{eq}$, $A$, and $b$. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common trick is to introduce variables $t_i$ that satisfy $|x_i - y_i| \leq t_i$.
In other words,
\begin{equation}
\tag{$\spadesuit$} t_i \geq x_i - y_i \quad \text{and} \quad t_i \geq -(x_i - y_i).
\end{equation}
You can replace each term $|x_i - y_i|$ in the objective function with $t_i$,
and add the constraints $(\spadesuit)$ to your list of constraints. The resulting quadratic program is close to being in the standard form you gave.

The vector of optimization variables is now $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ t \end{bmatrix}$.  To get closer to the standard form, let
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix} I & -I \\ -I  & -I \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $I$ is the identity matrix, and let
\begin{equation}
b = \begin{bmatrix} y \\ -y \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
The constraint $Ax \leq b$ is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
x - t \leq y \quad \text{and } -x - t \leq -y.
\end{equation}
So the inequality constraints have been expressed in the standard form.
The equality constraints can be handled in a similar way.

Comment: I've seen this trick in linear programming for minimizing the $l_1$ norm. The problem is I need the exact standard form given above so it can be put into a preexisting solver.

Comment: @mtiano Ok, I just gave some more details about that.